# What is the form of all $\Bbb{Z}$-bilinear maps $\Bbb{Z}/a \times \Bbb{Z}/b \to \Bbb{Z}/ab$ ? And ring hom?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, linear-transformations, integers

If $\phi : \Bbb{Z}/a \times \Bbb{Z}/b \to \Bbb{Z}/ab$ is $\Bbb{Z}$-bilinear.  Then the $(0,1)$ trick doesn't seem to work as $\phi(0,y) = 0$ since $\phi(0\cdot 0, y) = 0 \cdot \phi(0, y) = 0$ by linearity in the first argument.

So what trick does work?

I was thinking $\phi(x,y) = xy\phi(1,1)$ which seems to work, so $\phi$ is completely determined by its value on $\phi(1,1)$ and every bilinear map is of the form $(x,y) \mapsto c\cdot xy$.

Then if $(a,b) = 1$, what particular $c$ gives the ring isomorphism $\Bbb{Z}/a \times \Bbb{Z}/b \to \Bbb{Z}/ab$ induced by the CRT?

It seems as though $(0, y) \mapsto 0$ for all $y$ which doesn't seem bijective.

Lord Shark the Unknown said that the ring hom would be bilinear!

So I think I'm missing some important piece.

Comment: For abelian groups $A,B,C, \text{Hom}(A\oplus B, C)\simeq \text{Hom}(A,C)\oplus \text{Hom}(B,C)$.

Comment: Quotienting by $(X-n)$ really means "enforcing $X= n$". That's why $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$ (quotienting by $(X^2+1)$ means "enforcing $X = \sqrt{-1}$")